# Disocrd.py command

Tags: python, discord.py

I am coding a discord bot and i think there has got to be a much easier/ simpler way to detect messages using the prefix for commands (and easy to expand in future), my code at the moment just scans each message to see if it contains the exact command, maybe a class will help?

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # print message content
    print(message.content)
    # if the message came from the bot ignore it
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    # if the message starts with "!repeat" then say the message in chat
    if message.content.startswith("!repeat"):
        sentmessage = message.content.replace("!repeat", "")
        await message.channel.send(sentmessage)

    if "hello" in message.content.lower():
        await message.channel.send("Hello!")

    if message.content.startswith("!cleanup"):
        if not message.author.guild_permissions.administrator:
                await message.channel.send("You do not have permission to run this command!")
        else:
                num2c = 0
                num2c = int(message.content.replace("!cleanup", ""))+1
                print(num2c)
                await message.channel.purge(limit=num2c)
                num2c = num2c-1
                cleanmessage = str("Cleared  "+str(num2c)+" Messages.")
                await message.channel.send(cleanmessage, delete_after=5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `commands.Bot`, it has a built-in command system, here's an example:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

# enabling intents
intents = discord.Intents.default()

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)


@bot.command()
async def foo(ctx, *args):
    await ctx.send('whatever')


# You also have all the functionality that `discord.Client` has
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    # ...

    # you always need to add this when using `commands.Bot`
    await bot.process_commands(message)


bot.run('token')
```

Take a look at the [introduction](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html?highlight=commands)